# Can Blender use Virtual Memory?

Tags: rendering, image, memory-management

I have 2GB of RAM and I just want to use this program. Can Blender use Virtual Memory?

Getting one image rendered takes like 20-30 seconds and it's not even on the full resolution.

Comment: What Blender version are you using? And 20-30 Seconds to render one image with 2GB ram ist faster than I would've expected... Also the render time can vary with render settings and the scenery you build

Comment: If you feel your pc too limited to render high resolution images or animations, you could even experiment with web based render farms, i.e. sending your file to someone else to render, with powerful servers, often using some degree of parallelism. Obviously you will need to give something in exchange, money or whatever they accept for their machine time. Just ensure they support Blender (the version and features you're using), but usually you can get at least a trial account, although easily for a limited time or limited in resources

Answer (score 2):

All software uses virtual memory automatically. Operating systems usually take care of that. When you run out of RAM your storage devices are used. That is called paging. Storage drives are extremely slow compared to RAM so things slow down a lot when this happens. 20-30 seconds is extremely unimaginably fast for a render though. My renders, for example, would take 20 - 30 hours and even more per 4K still image if I rendered them on a single PC. Renders take lots of time. This cannot be solved by an answer on Stack Exchange I am afraid.

Comment: The Operating system is responsible for the memory management and paging, not blender.

Comment: That's what I meant to say.